# How to make a div (width: auto) adjust to nested divs (float left and fixed width)

Tags: html, css, css-float, css-position, positioning

I have a *panel* in my screen with `width:auto` and with a list of objects inside. The elements of this *list* have `float:left` and `width:380px`.
I want to centralize this panel in the screen inside a  *main div* (`display:flex; justify-content: center;`). It centralizes correctly when the number of items fit in one line, but when is needed another line, the panel use 100%, with a huge space from the last item in the line to the border of the panel. The images 1 and 2 exeplifies waht i have now. The image 3 is what i want.

green: *main div*,
grey: *panel*, 
blue: *list* item

image 1:

[image]

image2:

[image]

image3:

[image]

Why the div does not fit when is needed a second line?

Answer (score 0):

As I did not have an answer, I have solved the problem setting a max-width attribute to the panel, calculating the size of the amount of possible list items.